# Проблема с Ajax и киррилицей

Tags: ajax

Добрый день, у меня тут проблемка возникла.
Существует некая таблица,с помощью tableToJSON из нее формируется массив и отправляется на сервер,где он должен записаться в бд.
Все работает но есть одно но, вместо киррилицы получаю символы вида:
Р”РёСЃРїР»РµР№
помогите разобраться,а то я запутался во всех этих кодировках.

```js
        var table = $('#rept-table').tableToJSON();

        datasend = JSON.stringify(table);
      /*  alert(datasend);*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "тут урл скрипта",
            data: datasend
        }).done(function () {
```

```html
<?php
$dataSource = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=база;charset=UTF8;'; // тип СУБД, хост сервера и имя базы данных
$user = 'логин';
$password = 'пароль';

$db = new PDO($dataSource, $user, $password, $opt); // Подключаемся к базе данных


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
for ($k=0; $k<=count($data);)
{
$dataid = $data[$k]["ID"];
$dataname = $data[$k]["Название"];
$dataqtty = $data[$k]["Количество"];
$dataprice = $data[$k]["Цена"];
$datapricezak = $data[$k]["Закупка"];
$datadiscountqty = $data[$k]["КолОпт"];
$datadiscountprice = $data[$k]["ЦенаОпт"];

$db->exec("UPDATE oc_product SET quantity = '$dataqtty', price = '$dataprice', price_zak = '$datapricezak' WHERE product_id = '$dataid'");
$db->exec("UPDATE oc_product_description SET name = '$dataname' WHERE product_id = '$dataid'");
$db->exec("UPDATE oc_product_discount SET quantity = '$datadiscountqty', price = '$datadiscountprice' WHERE product_id = '$dataid'");
$k++;
}

?>
```

> посмотрите в консоли браузера какую кодировку вы запрашиваете и какую возвращает сервер. –

не особо шарю где это смотреть,но вроде нашел:

```html
Responce headers

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:public, max-age=2592000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 02 Feb 2017 12:33:48 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.10.2
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.29`


request headers

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:public, max-age=2592000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 02 Feb 2017 12:33:48 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.10.2
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.29`
```

Вродебы и там и там utf-8

Comment: посмотрите в консоли браузера какую кодировку вы запрашиваете и какую возвращает сервер.

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением iconv.

```
$dataname = iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251", $data[$k]["Название"]);
```